# The list is empty when i'm trying to fill it with google search results in firefox using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to search in google with a keyword and then assert that the fourth search result is specific word 
I've tried the same code on google chrome and it worked correctly
but the same code isn't worked in Firefox

```
public class Task4_Class {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.getProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","src\\test\\resources\\Drive\\geckodriver.exe"); 
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        //driver.close();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/ncr");
    }

    @Test
    public void searchInGoogleAndAssertTheFourthResult() {
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("TestNG");
        searchBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
          List <WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.className("ellip"));
          String fourthResult = results.get(3).getText();
          Assert.assertEquals(fourthResult, "TestNG Tutorial");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on *code doesn't work*

Comment: The list is always empty

Comment: Add some [wait](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Answer (score 0):

Your test was not waiting for the results to appear, so it would populate the list with empty elements because the page had not fully loaded. I updated your code to induce `WebDriverWait` and I also updated your XPath locator to something more robust. I tested this function and successfully retrieved the fourth search result.

```
    @Test
    public void searchInGoogleAndAssertTheFourthResult() {
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.XPath("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("TestNG");
        searchBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

          // wait for elements to exist
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//a/h3/div")));

          // get list of search result elements
          List <WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//a/h3/div"));

          String fourthResult = results.get(3).getText();

          // The exact title is not just "TestNG Tutorial", there is more text
          // need to change this to a contains
          Assert.assertTrue(fourthResult.contains("TestNG Tutorial"));

          // this one will not work
          Assert.assertEquals(fourthResult, "TestNG Tutorial");
    }
}
```

Note that your `Assert.assertEquals` statement will fail, because none of the search results are an exact match to "TestNG Tutorial". They have other text too, like "TestNG Tutorial: Annotations, Framework, Examples in ...". So you should run your assert against a `contains` query instead.

Comment: Thank you 
Yes I need it to fail
but can you tell me how to use contains as i tried but i can't

Comment: I did miss a parenthesis in the example I provided. but contains is used as such: `string.contains("another_string")` which returns true if `another_string` is found and false if not. more java docs here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-contains-method-example/